# Custom Login page redirect

Tags: controllers, login, redirect

I have created a custom login module which loads a page to be used by a particular customer group with its own URL `trade/account/login`. However, I've noticed that if a user tries to login with an incorrect username and password the page redirects back to the default `customer/account/login` URL.

Is there a way I can keep the customer on the same page if they enter the wrong login details?

I would like to keep them on
`trade/account/login` instead of redirecting to the customer account login `customer/account/login`

So far I only have this in my controller which loads the customer login page and form this works fine but doesn't keep the user on the same page if they enter the wrong username or password

```
<?php


class Namespace_Customlogin_AccountController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function LoginAction() {

      $this->loadLayout();
      $this->renderLayout();

    }
}
```

I'm looking into the AccountController.php but I cannot see where the redirect happens so would like to ask if anyone knows where I can override it in my module please?

Comment: show your `AccountController.php` file

Comment: @programmer_rkt Hi, please see my edit!

Comment: what is action post url of your form ?

Comment: what to know this url not function

Comment: @AmitBera Apologies, `trade/account/loginPost` not sure if I am even doing this correctly at the moment...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was quite simple in the end

```
<?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
<?php Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));?>
<?php else: Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

If the custom successfully logs in then redirect to the customer account page otherwise stay on the current URL

Comment: Amazing answer buddy ! **:)**

Answer (score 1):

When a browser requests for a url like `trade/account/login`, magento will first look which module that uses `trade` as it's `frontName`. Now let us assume your custom module uses `trade` as it's front name.

Next parameter is `account`. Magento will use this to find corresponding controller file that has to process. So thus magento now looks for `AccountController.php` file in your module's `controllers` directory.

Next parameter is using to find the action. Here it is `login`. Hence Magento will look for a `loginAction()` in `AccountController.php` which resides in your module. (I can see you have used `LoginAction()`. It will not work for sure ).

When you submit a login credentials, it will post this data to another action that is defined in `AccountController` which is in your module. For an example, default `AccountContoller` in `Mage_Customer` uses `logiPost` action for this purpose. I assume in the similar way, your `AccountController` also holds a validation method. If it is not there, you need to create one. Let it be `loginPost`.

So in this case, first you need to refer your login form to this action. It will somewhat looks like this.

```
<form name="form_name" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('trade/account/loginPost'); ?>">
      <!-- your form fields lives here -->
</form>
```

You have set url correctly.Now in your `AccountController`, you need to define `loginPost` action

File : `app\code\<codePool>\Namespace\Modulename\controllers\AccountController.php`

```
public function loginPostAction()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    //do your validation here
    if (<validation_fails>) {
          $this->_redirect('*/*/login'); // this will redirect to your login action
    }
}
```

As you can see `redirectUrl()` does the trick. It's parameter tells to magento, that we need to persist same current frontname and controller, but action should be `login`. Since current frontname and controllers are `trade` and `account`, it points towards your controller's `login` action

Use this data wisely and achieve your result. Happy debugging !

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, there are a few things that don't seem to be correct though. At the moment my log form works with `<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>` when I change it to `<?php echo $this->getUrl('trade/account/loginPost'); ?>` The form no longer works and redirects me to URL:`trade/account/loginPost` I'm not sure why but the syntax doesn't work..

Comment: I have taken `loginPost()` action as an example. I dont know whether it exist in your controller. This is not a full solution, rather gives you an insight what happends backside. Using this info dig more

Comment: Below answer is more appealing and less complex, What do u think ??